# Самый оптимальным вариантом создания сайдбара по прежнему является float?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: https://i.imgur.com/DofQfho.jpg]

Ребята, создавать сайдбары все также лучше с помощью float-ов? Flex'ы не лучшее решение для них, а грид не такой кроссбраузерный как float и гриды конечно для более сложных случаев. Я прав, или мое мнение в корне неправильно?

Comment: Чем вам flex'ы не угодили-то?

Comment: много проблем с ними при такой просто задаче. Если поискать можно много вопросов  с проблемами найти при создании сайдбара на флексах      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822650/creating-a-sidebar-within-a-flexbox-with-css

Comment: Вас обманули, с ними нет проблем

Comment: Собственно, по вашей же ссылке есть пример нормального сайдбара на флексах, что не так? Один лишь момент — я бы ещё завернул header и page в ещё один flex-контейнер, чтобы он автоматически заполнял всё по высоте и чтобы не нужно было городить костыли с height и calc

Comment: Кстати, сайдбар и контент на сайте из вашего скриншота не растягиваются на всю высоту окна, и если выкинуть требование растягиваться на всю высоту, то код можно значительно упросить